# Auto caching pages every minute or hour in Next.js 13 using App Router

Tags: caching, next.js

I'm building a football information site using Next.js: https://hangbongda.tv.

While measuring the site's PageSpeed, I noticed that first test usually gives out very low score but the following tests resulted in scores of almost 100. I suspect this is due to the caching mechanism of Next.js.

Currently I'm trying to cache a list of urls in Next.js periodically but haven't found a good solution yet. Is there anyway to solve that? Or are there any other problems that could affect the PageSpeed score of my site?